# Java OFBiz can not find symbol import java.io.FileOutPutStream and package org.apache.commons.fileupload does not exits?

Tags: java, ofbiz, apache-commons-fileupload

I want to user from file upload in Java OFBiz but when i do the following error occur:

```
import java.io.FileOutPutStream;
import org.apache.commons.fileUpload;
```

and other `io`, and apache packages bellow error occur:

```
Can not find symbol import java.io.FileOutPutStream Symbol: class FileOutPutStream
```

and another error

```
package org.apache.commons.fileupload does not exist.
```

I use eclipse , and the following is structure of path that code stored:
`hot-deploy->my_project->src->file.java` for Java files
`hot-deploy->my_project->widget->myScreens->fileUploadScreens.xml`
'hot-deploy->my_project->widget->myForms->fileUploadForms.xml'
But their is no `lib` folder inside `WEB-INF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import statements are wrong, they should be

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.*;
```

I recommend to set up a new OFBiz module using the ant target

```
./ant create-component
```

and answer the following questions. This will install a skeleton module in `hot-deply` and will be able to access everything OFBiz delivers OOTB.

You should also check if the OFBiz `.project` file for Eclipse is read correctly. You should see a lot of source (`src`) folders and libraries in the project properties/build path of your project. if not, your `.project` file is not recognized.

Comment: Now when i import like that one of the error still remained that indicate `can not find package org.apache.commons.fileupload` so please guide me how to solve that. Thanks for help.

Comment: Please answer the questions above (IDE) and show us the full code and where it is stored in your project structure. It's like looking into a crystal ball without these informations.

Comment: How was your project imported in Eclipse? commons-fileupload is in the OFBiz package so it should be found. I update my answer to some more hints to correctly setup your own OFBiz module.

Comment: Pardon me for asking again. Now my upload script is working properly, my project is in a path like:`/home/itadmin/apache-ofbiz` and file is uploaded in this path, but i have a lot of project in this path, i want to have an upload folder inside each project and upload the files of each project on that folder for example PMS project is in `apache-ofbiz/hot-deploy/pms` but when i define the target path inside Java code exception occur that indicate no such directory is existed, so how can i solve that ? I'm busy with this for along time thanks for help.

Comment: @jones it would be nice to reward sufficient answers with an upvote or accept, this would motivate others to answer your questions.

Comment: regarding your question: just check if the directory exists and create it if not.